Finding the minimum length word in a given string
Here's the problem statement from a coding platform -
Given a string S (that can contain multiple words), you need to find the word which has minimum length.
Note : If multiple words are of same length, then answer will be first minimum length word in the string. Words are separated by single space only.
Constraints :
1 <= Length of String S <= 10^5
I am aware of an efficient solution, but this is what I tried in my first attempt -
string = input().strip()
n=len(string)
words=string.split()
dic={}
for word in words:
    dic[word]=len(word)
word=""
if n!=0:
    mini = len(words[0])
    word=words[0]
    for wordss in dic:
        if (dic[wordss]<mini):
            word = wordss
            mini = dic[wordss]
print(word)

The problem is that it passes only 2 of the 5 test cases, which are hidden (not available to me). I am not really sure about the problem with this approach. What kind of edge cases am I missing out?

What is the purpose of a dictionary dic? Its items might not be insertion ordered in the old versions of Python, isn't it?

Which Python version are you using? One problem could be iteration order of the dictionary. From Python 3.7 onwards this is guaranteed to be insertion order. If iteration order is not insertion order it is not guranteed that you return the first word with minimal length.

It doesn't tell you why the test cases failed, right? It could just be TLE if the grader is super stringent. Hashing takes a while.

You don’t need to split the string to solve this. Just iterate through the string finding the distance between successive spaces.

your solution fails for the case where string is enormously long, 10^5 is very very long string and your solution is simply not efficient and hits the execution time limit

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

Thanks for the inputs. It's probably TLE (I might have to check the Python version they were using).

Why bother with a dictionary at all? You can just find the minimum as you go along.
string = input().strip()
minlen = len( string ) + 1
bestword = ""
for word in string.split():
    L = len( word )
    if L < minlen:
        minlen = L
        bestword = word
print( bestword )

Example:
Three blind mice see how they run
see


Thanks. I am aware of efficient solutions for this problem, but I was not sure why I was getting errors for using a dictionary for this problem. I used 2 lists, one to store the words and another for storing their lengths. Using min() and index() gave me back the first word with the minimum length.
